# algorithm to find optimized scheduling

Tags: algorithm, scheduled-tasks

I have 7 tasks t1-t7, each task has an execution time associated (t1 takes 1 time unit,t2 takes 5 etc).

You don't have to pay for communication cost between t1 and t2 if you do them in the same processor. If you do t1 on p1 and t2 on p2, you need 5 time units to transfer data from p1 to p2. (5 is the weight of edge t1-t2)

As illustrated in the right image, the communication c(1,2) and c(3,4) can be done in the same time, they both end at the end of 5 time unit.

The makespan is the time taken to finish all 7 tasks. Given that there are as many processors as I want to, which algorithm can I use to find the scheduling result with minimum makespan (or at least near the minimum one)?

Please note that the results in the right image may not be optimized.

[image]

Comment: Is the communication latency the same when you assign them in the same processor? otherwise what's to prevent allocating each task to a different processor?

Comment: Yes, communication take time. If you execute t2, you will need the data from t1. Its cost 5 unit time to do so (the edge t1-t2 in the graph above has weight 5).

Comment: I don't think the optimal solution can be found in reasonable time for a large number of nodes. You will probably have to brute-force through all possible combinations through recursion.

Comment: @navie that's not what Leeor meant. If all tasks were on a single processor would you still have to pay the same communication costs?

Comment: If the communication costs are always the same, Leeor's naive solution is guaranteed to be best: put every task on its own processor. The total time is going to be the longest path in your DAG, i.e. the shortest possible runtime. Phraes like "*Given that there are as many processors as I want to*" are funny.. That's how the word *span* is defined: time on infinite processors. The opposite is *work*, the time on a single processor.

Comment: sorry for being unclear: you don't have to pay for communication cost if you do t1 and t2 on the same processor.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: Brute cost will definitely cost a huge amount of time. Can we prove this point?

Comment: This is a variation of [Job Shop Scheduling] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) so methods like Constraint Programming or Integer Programming may apply. There might be special case algorithm for your case using just two processors. In the Job Shop nomenclature, a process would be called a machine or a resource.